# Laravel Database Connection Error even after successful Migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

## I'm on Laravel 7.

I'm not sure why I kept getting this error

> message: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: insert into `visitors`

on console/network tab.

I have correct database configs. I ran success migration, and I also verified that tables exists in my local db.

```
php artisan migrate                                                                                             
Migration table created successfully.                                                                                         
Migrating: 2015_04_20_182204_create_users_table                                                                               
Migrated:  2015_04_20_182204_create_users_table (0.17 seconds)                                                                
Migrating: 2015_04_21_140858_create_table_subscribes                                                                          
Migrated:  2015_04_21_140858_create_table_subscribes (0.07 seconds)                                                           
Migrating: 2015_05_13_134411_create_contacts_table                                                                            
Migrated:  2015_05_13_134411_create_contacts_table (0.06 seconds)                                                             
Migrating: 2015_05_13_135240_create_web_directories_table                                                                     
Migrated:  2015_05_13_135240_create_web_directories_table (0.02 seconds)                                                      
Migrating: 2015_05_15_195423_alter_table_web_directories                                                                      
Migrated:  2015_05_15_195423_alter_table_web_directories (0.02 seconds)                                                       
Migrating: 2015_06_02_223636_alter_table_contacts                                                                             
Migrated:  2015_06_02_223636_alter_table_contacts (0.01 seconds)                                                              
Migrating: 2015_06_03_142550_alter_table_users_2                                                                              
Migrated:  2015_06_03_142550_alter_table_users_2 (0.1 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_06_08_011835_create_logs_table
Migrated:  2015_06_08_011835_create_logs_table (0.13 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_06_08_151121_add_logo_path_to_users_table
Migrated:  2015_06_08_151121_add_logo_path_to_users_table (0.07 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_06_09_001047_add_cover_path_to_users_table
Migrated:  2015_06_09_001047_add_cover_path_to_users_table (0.05 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_06_12_111009_alter_table_users_4
Migrated:  2015_06_12_111009_alter_table_users_4 (0.11 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_08_19_134434_create_guests_table
Migrated:  2015_08_19_134434_create_guests_table (0.04 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_08_27_153239_alter_table_contacts_2
Migrated:  2015_08_27_153239_alter_table_contacts_2 (0.1 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_08_28_135733_create_table_blogs
Migrated:  2015_08_28_135733_create_table_blogs (0.15 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_09_16_114434_drop_web_directories_table
Migrated:  2015_09_16_114434_drop_web_directories_table (0.04 seconds)
Migrating: 2015_10_07_153216_create_table_visitors
Migrated:  2015_10_07_153216_create_table_visitors (0.02 seconds)
Migrating: 2016_03_18_045444_alter_guests_table_2
Migrated:  2016_03_18_045444_alter_guests_table_2 (0.06 seconds)
Migrating: 2016_03_19_214047_alter_guests_table_3
Migrated:  2016_03_19_214047_alter_guests_table_3 (0.04 seconds)
Migrating: 2017_02_27_110735_create_images_table
Migrated:  2017_02_27_110735_create_images_table (0.02 seconds)
Migrating: 2017_03_02_114249_create_skills_table
Migrated:  2017_03_02_114249_create_skills_table (0.01 seconds)
Migrating: 2017_03_22_220545_alter_images_table
Migrated:  2017_03_22_220545_alter_images_table (0.17 seconds)
Migrating: 2017_04_11_112639_alter_guests_table_4_11_2017
Migrated:  2017_04_11_112639_alter_guests_table_4_11_2017 (0.14 seconds)
Migrating: 2017_05_11_132108_create_youtube_downloads_table
Migrated:  2017_05_11_132108_create_youtube_downloads_table (0.02 seconds)
Migrating: 2017_08_17_155101_create_portfolios_table
Migrated:  2017_08_17_155101_create_portfolios_table (0.02 seconds)
Migrating: 2018_02_15_090145_create_portfolio_images_table
Migrated:  2018_02_15_090145_create_portfolio_images_table (0.01 seconds)
Migrating: 2018_02_26_010123_add_color_to_skill
Migrated:  2018_02_26_010123_add_color_to_skill (0.06 seconds)
Migrating: 2018_08_21_113930_clean_up_youtube
Migrated:  2018_08_21_113930_clean_up_youtube (0.05 seconds)
Migrating: 2018_08_21_121732_clean_up_subscribe
Migrated:  2018_08_21_121732_clean_up_subscribe (0.05 seconds)
Migrating: 2018_08_28_171714_create_instagram_table
Migrated:  2018_08_28_171714_create_instagram_table (0.01 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_03_20_164005_alter_users_table_3_20_2019
Migrated:  2019_03_20_164005_alter_users_table_3_20_2019 (0.1 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_03_26_143650_create_configs_table
Migrated:  2019_03_26_143650_create_configs_table (0.03 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_04_18_142703_create-fingerprinting_table
Migrated:  2019_04_18_142703_create-fingerprinting_table (0.03 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_09_05_192307_make_ddos_table
Migrated:  2019_09_05_192307_make_ddos_table (0.02 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_09_24_093912_create_ssh_table
Migrated:  2019_09_24_093912_create_ssh_table (0.02 seconds)
```

Am I facing some type of cache issues ?

I even try

```
⚡️  php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!
⚡️  php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
⚡️  php artisan view:clear
Compiled views cleared!
```

yield same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart your local server ?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to do that, now, it works. :)